# If $\varphi\to\phi$ is a tautology , then $\varphi\to\rho$ and $\rho\to\phi$ are also tautologies for some proposition $\rho$

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, alternative-proof

Let $\varphi$ and $\phi$ be two propositions such that $\vDash_{CL}\varphi\to\phi$, i.e. it's a tautology.

Prove that if $\varphi$ and $\phi$ have atoms in common, say, $p_1,...,p_n$, then there exist a proposition $\rho$ which only contains $p_1,...p_n$ such that $\vDash_{CL}\varphi\to\rho$ and $\vDash_{CL}\rho\to\phi$.

**Proof**

Let $\rho$ be the disjunction of all eligible conjunctions, such that each eligible conjunction contains
all and only statement letters that occur in both $\phi$ and $\varphi$. Then $\vDash_{CL}\varphi\to\rho$.

Now suppose that there is
some truth assignment that makes $\rho$ truth but $\phi$ false. Extend
this to a *truth assignment that covers the statement letters in $\varphi$*
that are not in $\phi$ (and so not in $\rho$). Some such truth assignment
still makes $\rho$ truth and $\phi$ inadequate, since it doesn’t change
anything about the statement letters in either formula. But it also
truthifies $\varphi$, per impossible since $\vDash_{CL}\varphi\to\phi$. So there
ain’t no such truth assignment. So $\vDash_{CL}\rho\to\phi$.

- I do not understand how this is achieved, $\vDash_{CL}\varphi\to\rho$, through the previous hypothesis.
- Also, in the part where says ...truth assignment that covers the statement letters in $\varphi$..., this means that a truth assignment might not cover all the statement letters in some formula?, for instance if $\phi=A\to B \land C$, then can I consider *v* such that only will apply to $(A\to B)$ and not $C$ ??
- Why the new extended function will make $\phi$ inadequate? I think the extended function should conserve $\phi$ as false.

  - And the last question, why the new extended function will make $\varphi$ true, why is this guaranteed?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: (I'm not a logician so I'm probably wrong but) can't you just pick $\rho = \phi$ and then you're done?

Comment: Using $\varphi$ and $\phi$ as different variables is a brave move...

Comment: @Harambe: I don't think so, since $\phi$ might have atoms which are not in $\varphi$, but $\rho$ must only contain atoms common to both $\varphi$ and $\phi$.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I didn't read the question, I just read the title and the proof...

Comment: See [Craig's interpolation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig_interpolation#Proof_of_Craig.27s_interpolation_theorem).

Comment: ...brave move, should I change the name of the variables?